# Java String search without a loop or if statement?

Tags: java, string, search

If I have a

```
String myName = "First Last";
```

How can I, without an if or any other conditionals/loops, return just the initials of the name??

I've been looking forever on this!

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework or something? I can think of plenty of ways that don't appear to use conditionals, but none that don't actually use them.

Comment: Why without conditionals or loops?  What have you tried so far?  And Brendan Long is correct, no matter what, you'll end up getting BNE or equivalent code when it's running.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to get most efficient way to search a String. I thought maybe there is a method to find where each space in a string is or something..

Comment: @Matt - The most efficient way is to use a loop and `if` statement ;)

Comment: Are you allowed to use goto? :)

Answer (score 6):

Since you can't loop or use conditionals, you can't check anything, so this is your only choice:

```
/**
 * Gets the initials from a String. Note: Only works on the String "First Last"
 */
String getInitials(String s) {
    return "FL";
}
```

Comment: +1: Thinking outside The Box.  You found the answer I couldn't think of.

Answer (score 5):

Without *some* form of branching/looping/conditionals *somewhere* this is impossible (to handle in a generic fashion), but who says *we* need to do the branching? ([Regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) are powerful beasts -- sometimes too powerful, and always beasts...)

```
String name = "First Last";
String initials = name.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");
```

Please note that your mileage will vary: consider [Steve McQueen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_McQueen) (or [Президент Российской Федерации](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Russia)) as counter examples. Modification of the regular expression above is a viable solution (that is "left as an exercise" ;-), but pay heed to the warning about regular expressions.

Happy coding.

Comment: Love the pathological counterexamples.  Like fire, regular expressions are only dangerous if they go out of control and get all over everything.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `charAt(int)` method to get a character.
2. Find location of last name using `indexOf(String)` method

The sample code is below.

```
String initial_name = myName.charAt(0)+"."+myName.charAt(myName.indexOf(' ')+1)+".";
```

Comment: Good one!  I feel a little dumb for not thinking of that!

Answer (score 0):

OK, how about this:

```
String myName = "First Last";
String[] names = myName.split("\s+");
return names[0] + names[1];
```

Note of course that this only works for exactly two names separated by some whitespace.  Finding a different number of initials probably requires a regex or some conditionals :D